# What happens when deleting a table on bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

When deleting a table on bigquery, that table name becomes reserved or something for some time? Or is it possible to create another table (at the same dataset) with the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to create new table with the same name just after the delete operation has finished. I suggest the following test: You can create dataset then delete is, as soon as deletion is completed you can create new dataset with the same name. Until the delete operation is completed the table name is reserved.

Important remark from [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#deleting_tables)

"It's possible to restore a table within 2 days of deletion. By leveraging snapshot decorator functionality, you may be able to reference a table prior to the deletion event and then copy it. Note the following:

- You cannot reference a deleted table if you have already created a new table with the same name in the same dataset.
- You cannot reference a deleted table if you deleted the dataset that housed the table, and you have already created a new dataset with the same name."